# Geometry Node : Instancing a Grease Pencil Animation but at different times

Tags: geometry-nodes, grease-pencil, instances

Let's say I have made an FX of a single droplet of water in a Grease Pencil object.

I want to be able to achieve this :
[image: The Goal]

But I don't want to do it the way I did it (copying & pasting & manually placing + offseting each grease pencil object in the scene and the timeline)
I would like to do it procedurally so I've used Geometry nodes to make this :

[image: Almost there]

[image: Geometry Node]

Almost there ! I could manage to randomize the scale, position and rotation but I can't seem to find a way to randomize the time of instance of the GP: They all play at the same time !

Is there a way to solve this ?

This would be really useful to quickly setup all sorts of FX

Comment: Have you tried the [Time Offset](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/grease_pencil/modifiers/modify/time_offset.html) modifier ?

Comment: I've been using it to offset the timing of the different FXs but I still had to  "manually"  go on each GP Object to change values for the modifier. :)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is not possible right now with "just" GN.

But...(although i am sure you don't wanna hear it or already know it) you can copy your grease pencil animation and offset your animation for each copy and make a collection of these objects and plug this into your point instance node.

Comment: Ay, at least I know I just can't do it that way. Thank you for your reply and your suggestion. ;)